# azure devops how can i make a pipeline that will update 2 branches?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a pipeline for the master, when a pull request is happening for the master the pipeline will check it and if everything is okay it will deploy it on the website, on the masterbranch.

But what i want to do is when i do a pull request for the master, i also want to update the hotfix branch with the same build. So once i have made a pull request for the master branch that it also will update the master branch but also the hotfix branch with the latest version. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: The reasoning behind wanting to do this in the first place would improve the discussion. From my point of view the idea of merging anything into the master branch while a hotfix branch is under development seems wrong. When the necessity of a hotfix is identified, we halt all pull requests into master and complete and merge the hotfix into the master, deploy it and only then resume other PRs, which get the hotfix from the master. A hotfix branch lives a minimal amount and therefore this usually doesn't have such a big impact. But maybe your scenario is somehow different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not able to update hotfix branch automatically if there is no change on it. You need to perform a merge from master branch to hotfix branch, and specify a trigger in your YAML file as below:

```
trigger:
- master
- hotfix
```

In this way, both master branch and hotfix branch can trigger this pipeline.

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/ci-build-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-mulitple-branches?view=azure-devops

Comment: Ah okay, yes what i wanted is that once the master is build succesfull that it will push that build on/in to the hotfix branch automatically. So that the hotfix branch als runs the newest version

Comment: How can i achieve this because i dont understand this

Comment: Yes but where can i find the specific command line for that to add to azure pipelines

Comment: Could you maby give me a example code or something because iam not experienced with azure devops

Comment: Is the reference case helpful?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you have to download the extension from the marketplace called create pull request